# Machine-Learning - Concept / Recommendations

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-classification

Hi I'm new at machine learning and therefore looking for a text classification solution. Could one recommend me a nice framework written in java? I thought about using WEKA, but also heard about MALLET. What's better, where are the main differences?

My target is to classify unlabeled text. Therefore I prepared about 18 topics and 100 text for each topic for learning.

What would you recommend to do? Would also appreciate a nice little example or hint of how to proceed.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very minimal text data set, you could use any library - it wouldn't really matter. More advanced options would require more data than you have to be meaningful, so its not an issue worth considering. The simple way text classifications problems are handled is to use a [Bag of Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) model and a linear classifier. Both Weka and MALLET support this.

Personally, I find Weka to be a pain and MALLET to be poorly documented / out of date when it is, so I use [JSAT](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/). There is an example on doing spam classification [here](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/wiki/LoadingTextDataSpam).

(bias warning, I'm the author of JSAT).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I will take a look at JSAT. What would you say, what is the min. text data set adequate learning?

Comment: It is always problem dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Since your task is fairly simple and as you mentioned you're new at ML, I'd recommend you to use weka as it is easy to use and has a large user community.

Otherwise here are some General Purpose Machine Learning frameworks in Java that you can have a look at:

- Datumbox - Machine Learning framework for rapid development of Machine Learning and Statistical applications
- ELKI - Java toolkit for data mining. (unsupervised: clustering, outlier detection etc.)
- H2O - ML engine that supports distributed learning on data stored in HDFS.
- htm.java - General Machine Learning library using Numenta’s Cortical Learning Algorithm
- java-deeplearning - Distributed Deep Learning Platform for Java, Clojure,Scala
- JAVA-ML - A general ML library with a common interface for all algorithms in Java
- JSAT - Numerous Machine Learning algoirhtms for classification, regresion, and clustering.
- Mahout - Distributed machine learning
- Meka - An open source implementation of methods for multi-label classification and evaluation (extension to Weka).
- MLlib in Apache Spark - Distributed machine learning library in Spark
- Neuroph - Neuroph is lightweight Java neural network framework
- ORYX - Simple real-time large-scale machine learning infrastructure.
- RankLib - RankLib is a library of learning to rank algorithms
- RapidMiner - RapidMiner integration into Java code
- Stanford Classifier - A classifier is a machine learning tool that will take data items and place them into one of k classes.
- WalnutiQ - object oriented model of the human brain
- Weka - Weka is a collection of machine learning algorithms for data mining tasks

Source: [Awesome Machine Learning](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#java-general-purpose)